# How to call a node.js API from react to download a file

Tags: node.js, download

Currently my API is connected to the Dataverse which responds with an Object with a file information, and the information I have in the API to send to the frontend is for example:

```
{
  id:1;
  filename: example.pdf ;
  documentbody: (really long string);
  mimetype:'application/pdf'
}
```

And I want a user in React to be able to download this file if a button is clicked.
I have searched but haven't yet found a way to trigger the download in the backend neither in the frontend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in Ur download function create an anchor tag programmatically set href and download stuff and then trigger the click event programmatically to start downloading.

```
download(){
    const downloadLink = document.createElement('a');

    downloadLink.href = linkSource;
    downloadLink.download = filename;
    downloadLink.click();
}
```